# New custom keycloak message

Tags: keycloak

We were trying to add a new keycloak message type in order to be used in all languages and not having a predefined value in an authenticator we are implementing but the issue there is that we cannot extend the Message.class.

Comment: Why are you trying to extend that class? Can you elaborate more about the scenario and a sample of a message/key you're trying to overwrite?

Comment: I am not trying to overwrite anything, i just want to create a new one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't be needed to extend the Message class. You can put your messages in the property files as mentioned in Keycloak [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#messages). Then you should be able to look them up in your templates like this:

```
${msg("your.custom.message.key")}
```

and also in your backend code like this (if needed):

```java
Theme theme = session.theme().getTheme(Theme.Type.LOGIN); // or use any other theme types that you put your messages in
Locale locale = session.getContext().resolveLocale(user);
Properties messagesBundle = theme.getMessages(locale);

messagesBundle.get("your.custom.message.key")
```